# External backup hard drives keeps dropping transfer rate by orders of magnitude

Tags: usb, hard-drive, external-hdd, rsync, io

Using Ubuntu 16.04 on Dell Inspiron 7570

I have been trying to backup my `home` to an external USB 3.0 4TB Seagate drive. I bought 3 about a year ago, and only ever opened 1 for use. I have the same thing happen on **all** 3. They all were NTFS formatted data partitions.

I am running `rsync -ahvW --partial --progress --info=progress2 $HOME /media/$USER/Seagate\ Expansion\ Plus\ Drive/`.

The transfer rate is on average about 60MB/s - 80MB/s for periods, while I saw rate peak at ~110MB/s. About 23 GB into the sync, the rate just plummets to on the order of 10-100 KB/s. I cancelled the transfer on 2 of them to try to restart, un-plugged and reconnected them, `sudo umount /path/to/external/HDD ; sudo mount /path to/external/HDD /mnt`, rebooted, really anything to try to get the speed back. The first drive (I have used before and has data on it) has trouble mounting at this point from bad sectors. I can still `ls` dirs in the times it mounts. Transfer rate still slow.

The second drive I opened **new from box**, same behavior, and it has trouble mounting now.

The 3rd shows the same transfer speed changes, I am letting run without disturbance now, but since I have many GBs left to sync, it will take forever.

Comment: You may try to boot your PC with a recent Ubuntu on liveUsb, try again and see if it is a software issue

Comment: Didn't change anything ☹️